# jQuery AJAX POST to PHP file to UPDATE database not updating

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I'm trying to build a small CMS system, I want to use AJAX and jQuery to do so.

If I do not use AJAX the code works, I have no idea why the data is not being passed properly.  AJAX success returns "Success"

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aboutContent = $('#aboutContent').attr('value');
    $('#aboutUpdate').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/update.php",
            data: "aboutUpdate="+aboutContent,
            beforeSend: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('processing...'); },
            success: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('Saved Successfully!').delay(500).fadeOut(250); },
            error: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#ff464a').html('An error occurred!').delay(500).fadeOut(250); }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<?
$query = "SELECT * FROM pageContent WHERE page = 'about'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <form id="aboutUpdate" method="post">
        <textarea class="editor" id="aboutContent" cols="50" rows="20"><? echo $rows['content']; ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Now"><span class="updateStatus" id="aboutStatus"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
<?
}
?>
```

Here is the PHP (scripts/update.php):

```
$aboutContent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aboutUpdate']);
if(isset($_POST['aboutUpdate'])){
    $query="UPDATE pageContent SET content='$aboutContent' WHERE page='about'";
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($result){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else{
        echo "Update Error";
    }
}
else{
    header("location:http://google.com");
}
```

Comment: have you connected the page called via ajax to database ? ?

Comment: Have you enabled `<?php ini_set('display_errors'); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` to see if anything is happening there? also, try stepping through your code by moving around `exit('Exiting Application After Line n');`

Comment: @coosal I have jquery being called

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have that already, AJAX response is 4 or success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Here is how:

First on the TEXTAREA I need to specify the attribute

```
name="aboutUpdate"
```

so the PHP isset can pull the data.

Second, I noticed a variable was 'undefined' when submitting.

```
var aboutContent = $('#aboutContent').attr('value');
```

Here is the working Javascript:

```
$('#aboutUpdate').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/update.php",
        data: { aboutUpdate: $('#aboutContent').attr('value') },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('processing...');
        },
        success: function(){
            $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('Saved Successfully!').delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#ff464a').html('An error occurred!').delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<?
$query = "SELECT * FROM pageContent WHERE page = 'about'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <form id="aboutUpdate" method="post">
        <textarea class="editor" id="aboutContent" name="aboutUpdate" cols="50" rows="20"><? echo $rows['content']; ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Now"><span class="updateStatus" id="aboutStatus"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
<?
}
?>
```

PHP update.php:

```
$aboutContent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aboutUpdate']);
if(isset($_POST['aboutUpdate'])){
    $query="UPDATE pageContent SET content='".$aboutContent."' WHERE page='about'";
    $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($result){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else{
        echo "Update Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your Ajax function like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/update.php",
        data: { aboutUpdate: aboutContent },
        beforeSend: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('processing...'); },
        success: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#017c04').html('Saved Successfully!').delay(500).fadeOut(250); },
        error: function(){ $('#aboutStatus').fadeIn(250).css('color', '#ff464a').html('An error occurred!').delay(500).fadeOut(250); }
    });
```

Notice the change in the POST data line.

Comment: I tried that, same issue, database has no changes. Just tried again, still failing.

Comment: Add an else statement to the end of your PHP script to see if the database update is actually going though.

Comment: Hmm, how about if you change your MySQL to: `"UPDATE pageContent SET content='".$aboutContent."' WHERE page='about'"`

Comment: @Johnathan Bristow  I tried, still no update on the database, if I set upload.php POST to GET and call upload.php?aboutUpdate=blah blah it works.

Comment: does the text in your text area contains special characters like ' or " ?

Comment: @ZiedJaballah Not currently, currently it is 'test' without ', it will be HTML though in the end.

Comment: you are not specifying the action method in the form tag may be the error is there. try to test with `isset` on your `$aboutContent` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely sure, that with this `data: "aboutUpdate="+aboutContent` you are sending something totaly wrong.

It should be `data: {aboutUpdate: aboutContent}`

Plus I'm not sure, that textarea actually has attribute value. Try

```
$('#aboutContent').val()
```

or

```
$('#aboutContent').text()
```